# iOS/Swift(UI) Efficient implementation of Background calculation thread always running - GCD case?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch

To simplify my problem: I have a **huge calculation function** with **3 inputs** and **2 outputs**. My input variables are `@Published` SwiftUI variables inside a SwiftUI `ObservableObject`. The UI does modify these input variables quite often, if the user takes actions. Output variables are also `@Published` variables inside the same class. As said, the background calculation is huge - therefore, I need to run the calculation all the time when one of the three inputs changes. If the inputs change during calculation, a new calculation is needed with the current (new) values. This should be as efficient and performant as it gets.

I come from Android programming and in Java I created a very efficient solution by having a background thread that runs all the time, sleeps when no new calculation is needed and gets woken up (notified in Java language) when one of the inputs changed. It then calculates the new results by request the most-current input parameters. If these input parameters changed during calculation, the thread does another calculation with the most-current, and so on...

But, I'm not sure how to achieve this in Swift. I see we can submit tasks to GCD on an extra queue for background processing. So, it is not possible to have a background thread running, being paused and waiting for new inputs, and calculating them - correct? I would need to send calculation tasks to the GCD queues all the time. I read and tried around a lot and created my first solution, which works but doesn't work well and efficient, I think:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject, CalculatorDelegate {
  var calculator = Calculator()
  @Published var input1: Date
  @Published var input2: Int
  @Published var input3: Bool

  init() {
    calculator.delegate = self

    $input1.sink { [weak self] in
      self?.calculator.requestUpdate()
    }.store(...)

    $input2.sink { [weak self] in
      self?.calculator.requestUpdate()
    }.store(...)

    $input3.sink { [weak self] in
      self?.calculator.requestUpdate()
    }.store(...)
  }

  func createRequest() -> Data.Request { return Data.Request(input1, input2, input3) }
  func setResult(result: Data) { ... }
}
```

And the calculator itself:

```
class Calculator {
    var delegate: CalculatorDelegate?
    
    private static let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "asdf", qos: .userInteractive)
    private let blInstance = BL()
    private var reqForUpdate = false
    
    func register(for requestProvider: CalculatorDelegate) {
        self.delegate = requestProvider
    }
    
    func requestUpdate() {
        if !reqForUpdate {
            reqForUpdate = true
            scheduleUpdate()
        }
    }
    
    private func scheduleUpdate() {
        Calculator.queue.async { [weak self] in
            if let request = self?.delegate?.createRequest() {
                self?.reqForUpdate = false
                let result = self?.blInstance.calc(request: request)
                
                if let result = result {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.delegate?.setResult(result: result)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol CalculatorDelegate {
    func createRequest() -> Data.Request
    func setResult(result: Data)
}
```

Is this a good strategy? I think it's too complicated and it does not seem to be as efficient as the Android version I described above (having a endless running calculation background thread waiting for new data or processing as long as new data is there). Furthermore, is GCD the right tool here to use? I'm not sure...

I simplified the code to underline the important parts. Thanks a lot for your help or hints.

Comment: A Java Thread is just an abstraction for encapsulating units of work. It isn't continually running. It just encapsulates state and execution is dispatched when there is work to do. On iOS you can dispatch work onto a GCD queue or you can use an OperationQueue or even just a combine pipeline. Can you explain more how your calculation operates?  Will it complete before new data arrives?  If new data arrives before it completes do you need to be able to interrupt/restart the computation?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> So, it is not possible to have a background thread running, being paused and waiting for new inputs, and calculating them - correct?

GCD does something very similar to this: It has a pool of “worker threads”, and when you dispatch something to a queue, it just grabs an available worker thread to run the dispatched code. This eliminates the overhead of spinning up a new thread. This results in a highly performant multi-threading mechanism.

GCD abstracts the developers away from managing threads and avoids the creation and destruction of threads unnecessarily. Just use GCD (or operation queues or `async`-`await`) and enjoy efficient thread utilization.

> is GCD the right tool here to use?

GCD works, but I would also consider the `async`-`await` concurrency system or operation queues.

Specifically, a key design requirement is that you want to be able to cancel your calculation (so you can presumably start another). GCD’s `DispatchWorkItem` supports cancelation, but operation queues and `async`-`await` arguably handle this more elegantly. So, while you could use GCD, I would personally suggest `async`-`await` if supported by my target OS (e.g., iOS 13 and later), and use operation queue if I needed to support older operating systems.

But whether dispatch queue, operation queue, or `async`-`await`, you will want to participate in “cooperative cancelation”. Specifically, you will have your time-consuming calculation periodically check the respective `isCancelled` property, exiting the calculation if `true`.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

@IBAction func didTapCalculate(_ sender: Any) {
    ...

    task = Task.detached {
        try await self.calculate()

        await MainActor.run { [weak self] in
            ...

            self?.task = nil
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapCancel(_ sender: Any) {
    task?.cancel()
    task = nil
}

func calculate() async throws {
    ...

    repeat {
        // check to see if task has been canceled

        try Task.checkCancellation()                // or `if Task.isCancelled { return }`

        // perform iteration of calculations here

        // now update the UI if necessary

        if shouldUpdateUI {
            Task { [value] in
                await updateLabel(with: value)
            }
        }
    } while shouldKeepCalculating
}

@MainActor
func updateLabel(with value: Double) async {
    label.text = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of Combine's `ObservableObject` and `sink` for the inputs is highly non-standard. That should only be used when you want to `assign` the output of a Combine pipeline to an `@Published` so isn't the right approach here. I recommend a standard SwiftUI approach like this async calculator example below. Note the use of `@Binding` and `.task(id:)`.

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
       let formatter = NumberFormatter()
       formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
       return formatter
   }()

struct CalculatorView: View {
    @State var calc = Calculator()
    
    var body: some View {
        InputsView(calc: $calc)
        OutputsView(calc: calc)
    }
}

struct Calculator: Equatable {
    var input1: Int = 0
    var input2: Int = 0
    
    func calculate() async -> Int {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
        return input1 + input2
    }
}

struct InputsView: View {
    @Binding var calc: Calculator // gives write-access to the inputs
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Input 1")
            TextField("Text", value: $calc.input1, formatter: formatter)
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Input 2")
            TextField("Text", value: $calc.input2, formatter: formatter)
        }
    }
}

struct OutputsView: View {
    let calc: Calculator // gives read access to the inputs and body is called when they change.
    @State var result = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Result")
            Text("\(result)")
        }
        .task(id: calc) { // runs on appear and when calc inputs changes, automatically cancelled if already started and on disappear.
            result = await calc.calculate()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi @malhal! Thanks a lot for your reply! That seems to be a great and Swift(UI)y solution. Although, I'm using a ViewModel defined as `ObservableObject` holding those input variables as `Published` properties. The whole app depends on them. For me, it seems to be not the "best" solution to pack those input variables into a struct (`Calculator` in your code). Otherwise, I would access them separately in UI.  Do you see a problem in adding `task(id: viewModel.varX) { ... }` in the UI three times for all three input variables? Of course, initially the calculation will be done three times...

Comment: The task is cancelled if it hasn't finished by the time there is a new value and a new one is started. However, supporting cancellation of the async task all the way through is challenging, which is what you need to do make it only do one full calculation instead of three.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that, thanks! Do you have another idea how I could leave those three variables separated inside the ViewModel instead of packing them all in a struct? That would completely change the code and I'm not sure if I would still be able to listen to them separately.

And secondly, I'm not sure if there is still a better solution than this (great) one out there, as my calculation always uses current values and I want calculation always to finish (to get intermediate values). It should just recalculate after finishing if there was a change in input variables.

Comment: Another way would be to make it a model instead of a view model. Then its fine to use an ObservableObject and you can also use Combine to process the data, e.g., Publishers.CombineLatest($input1, $input2, $input3).